# Pasting HTML string with line breaks into a single Excel cell

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm trying to insert HTML/RTF formatted text into a single Excel cell, preserving text formatting (colour, bold, italic etc.).

The problem is that if the text contains line breaks (`<br>`), parts of the text between the breaks is inserted into separate cells.

[image: screenshot of the problem]

I tried `<b style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;" />`, but it seems to be ignored by Excel's parser and treated like a normal `<br>`.

A lot of topics on forums say that mso-data-placement:same-cell lets you have new line breaks inside a cell, but in my case this style is ignored.

How do I achieve text formatting and line breaks when pasting text into a single cell?

My code (simplified a bit):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change2(ByVal Target As Range, ByVal sht As Worksheet)
Dim objData As MSForms.DataObject
Dim sHTML As String

Application.EnableEvents = False
Set objData = New MSForms.DataObject
sHTML = "<html>ABC<br>EFG" & "<br style=" & Chr(34) & "mso-data-placement:same-cell;" & Chr(34) & " />" & "XYZ</html>"
objData.SetText  sHTML
objData.PutInClipboard

sht.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode Text" ', NoHTMLFormatting:=False
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `<br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;"/>` to work it needs to be in a `<TD>` in a `<TABLE>`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change2(ByVal Target As Range, ByVal sht As Worksheet)
    Const br = "<br style=""mso-data-placement:same-cell;""/>"
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim objData As MSForms.DataObject
    Set objData = New MSForms.DataObject

    With CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
        .Append_3 "<HTML>"
        .Append_3 "<TABLE>"
        .Append_3 "<TR>"
        .Append_3 "<TD>"
        .Append_3 "ABC"
        .Append_3 br
        .Append_3 "EFG"
        .Append_3 br
        .Append_3 "XYZ"
        .Append_3 "</TD>"
        .Append_3 "</TR>"
        .Append_3 "</TABLE>"
        .Append_3 "</HTML>"
        objData.SetText .ToString
        objData.PutInClipboard   
    End With

    sht.Paste
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Note: It might be helpful to use the TagBuilder class that I have in my CodeReview post [Creating HTML using a Builder Pattern](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/178814/creating-html-using-a-builder-pattern)