# HTML with line breaks in one single excel cell - getting rid of one additional cell space

Tags: html, excel

I know this was discussed before,

[[Pasting HTML string with line breaks into a single excel cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46964106/pasting-html-string-with-line-breaks-into-a-single-excel-cell])

but my excel acts differently. If I enter this code:

```
<html><b>first line<br/>Second line</html>
```

I get

[image]

But if I add ="mso-data-placement:same-cell;":

```
<html><b>first line<br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;" />Second line</html>
```

I get

[image]

In other words, I get one extra line (two cell spaces) with `"<br/>"` compared to other posts that I found. Then `="mso-data-placement:same-cell` ;" gets rid of one cell space, but I still have second line in the second cell. I want to have both entries in the same cell but a different line, like this:

[image]

I have office 2010, because that is all I can have at my work. Is there a solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a working solution at the link you posted.

This:

```
<html><table><tr><td>first line<br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;" />
Second line</td></tr></table></html>
```

works fine for me: it's rendered in a single cell.

Comment: Thank you. I misunderstood the issue in the link above that "mso-data-replacement" was not making a difference at all. Your solution does work for me.

Comment: as of now 2024 that does not work (anymore)

Comment: Still working for me in Office 365 (Excel v 2312)